# No access to the owner of the Google brand account anymore

Tags: youtube, google-account

As an NGO, we created a Google brand account some years ago but unfortunately the owner of the account left the organization and we can't contact him. So we are still able to manage our youtube channel but we are not able to get full control over the account. How could we reclaim the full ownership of our account ?

Comment: [Google Cloud Platform](http://cloud.google.com/) doesn't handle Google Brand Accounts but Youtube work with them. https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9367690?hl=en Could you please clarify if your issue is related with GCP or Youtube?

Comment: I could not find a tag that was fitting my issue, there is no misc google tag. It's not related to google clou platform but It's a google account issue, not a youtube one so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google-Cloud-Platform specific use cases should be reported on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

I have already created this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/177323745) for you so the right team would handle it for you.

As my colleague indicated on this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/177323745), this should be handled by [YouTube Support](https://support.google.com/youtube/community?hl=en).

For this, you would need to submit an [new question](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/new?hl=en).

Comment: so according to the answer in the issue tracker, it is not the right place do you know where I have to go to get an answer, I could not find anything about that ?

Comment: Updated my answer, and if you still need further help, let me know.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, I will do so.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, but I would like to know if there is a possibility out someone at youtube, it's my last attempt before recreating a new youtube channel.

Comment: @antham Give me a few days and I'll try my best

Comment: Ok thank you I really appreciate your help

Comment: @antham We'd need to further discuss this on the Public issue I shared with you on my answer. Can you make sure to cc yourself on it, then confirm with me that you did.

Comment: I answered to the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177323745 , is it what you wanted me to do ?

Comment: So after talking with the youtube support, there is no solution to this problem if you can't be in touch with the current owner of the account, thanks you very much for your help.